# How was Satyaki able to fight against Guru Dronacharya for a whole day?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, war, dronacharya

[*Satyaki*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyaki) was a student of *Arjuna*.

How was Satyaki able to fight against *Guru Dronacharya* for a whole day on Fourteenth day of [Kurukshetra War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurukshetra_War) ? Was he that skilled?

Reference: [Kurukshetra War : Fourteenth day - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyaki#Fourteenth_day) states:

> Satyaki defends Yudhishthira from Drona, who was attempting to capture the emperor in Arjuna's absence. Rescuing Dhristadyumna from Drona, Satyaki engages in a long fight with Drona, taking up the morning's fight. Drona gets so frustrated by Satyaki, that he even uses divine weapons, which Satyaki counters using his knowledge of divine weapons from his education under Arjuna. Eventually, Satyaki tires, and he is wounded by Drona's arrows. He is rescued by a new attack from the Upapandavas. Ultimately, Satyaki manages to stall Drona long enough that Duryodhana, frustrated with Drona's lack of progress, withdraws Drona to focus on the conflict with Arjuna.

As usual, Wikipedia does not provide any references. Also, I do not trust this narration completely. Nor is it detailed. Hence, this question.

Comment: You questioned authority and bot army is behind you. Enjoy.

Comment: hahahaa, I have some idea who is behind, its not related to my questions, its related to the answers I am posting

Comment: answers, i dint get you?

Comment: Some people are not liking that I am using saints of the current ages in my answers

Comment: I read [this](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/537/validity-of-references) question on meta. You can get who that is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39259/discussion-between-b--t-and-amit-saxena).

Comment: -2 for downvote & +5 for upvote. Their hate will do more good than bad.

Comment: I would rather like to see it as we are all on the same side with difference of opinions :)

Comment: You are providing references to your all questions. Well, it looks like you got me wrong. You need not provide them for all questions.

Comment: @TheDestroyer No, no, this reference by added by B i t in his edit :)

Comment: Interesting question. There are so many such interesting finds in the Mahabharat that can give good discussion points.